# How to find a record with an empty field value using VBA in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a bit confused on how exactly VBA views empty field values in a table/datasheet because I'm trying to use `Recordset.FindFirst` method to locate a record within my datasheet, but if the record contains a field that is empty, it cannot locate the record.

For example, here's what my table may look like:

```
FieldOne   FieldTwo
123        SomeName1
456        
789        SomeName2
```

For record `456`, the value in `FieldTwo` is empty. The datatype for `FieldOne` and `FieldTwo` is a **Short Text**.

Assume `myDatasheet` is linked to the above table with those mentioned records.

I attempt to find the record `123` like so:

```
Dim crit As String
crit = "FieldOne = '" & Me.textBoxOne & "' And " & _
       "FielTwo = '" & Me.textBoxTwo & "'"

With myDatasheet.Form
    .RecordsetClone.FindFirst crit 

    If Not .RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "FOUND"
    Else
        MsgBox "NOT FOUND"
    End If
End With
```

Where the value in `Me.textBoxOne` is `123` and in `Me.textBoxTwo` is `SomeName1` and I get a `FOUND`.

However, if I try to find record `456` using `Me.textBoxOne` as `456` and `Me.textBoxTwo` as `""`, I get a `NOT FOUND`.

There's got to be something syntactically wrong with my code. What should the correct criteria be?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `[FieldTwo] Is Null`?

Comment: Try building your criteria with `BuildCriteria`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/224961/3820271 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198954/3820271

Comment: Would it be an option to use the [Nz function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)? It turns Null into empty Strings by default and can be used in SQL statements as well, so I guess it would also work with the above criteria. E.g. "Nz(FieldTwo) = '" & Nz(Me.textBoxTwo) & "'", then the Field value as well as the Textbox value could be either empty strings or Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Null` is not the same as an empty string. Your *"empty"* field likely is `Null`, and comparing `Null` to any string resuts in `Null`, which gets parsed as `False`.

While you can add some logic to check if your form field is null or an empty string, and then use `Is Null` in the condition, like KostasK suggests, there's a simple workaround: just concatenate an zero-length string to your field. That will cause Null values to become zero-length strings, making them pass the comparison:

```
crit = "FieldOne = '" & Me.textBoxOne & "' And " & _
       "FielTwo & '' = '" & Me.textBoxTwo & "'"
```

Note that this will invalidate any indexes, which might lead to performance issues in very select situations.