# Query: typing multiple criteria in a textbox form

Tags: ms-access, query-builder

My question is about how to query multiple values in a field in a form in Access 2016. In the form, I have 3 textboxes: Date1, Date2 and studentID (txtstd_id)
In txtbox1 I select date 1
In txtbox2 I select date 2
In txtbox3 I type one value (e.g, student_ID)

Below I show SQL for dates and SQL for std_id. I used the query builder.

```
SQL1 = Between [Forms]![frm_search]![txtdatte1] AND [Forms]![frm_search]![txtdatte2]
SQL2 = [Forms]![frm_search]![txtstd_id]
```

SQL1 and SQL work well.

Now, what I need is to enter in txtstd_id more than one value -using OR clause- hoping that Access will returns all txtstd_id values between the date range selected.

Any idea is welcome.

I hope this example helps me to be clear:
I have a form with three text boxes: one for Day1, one of Day2 and one for Room.
The for also has a Search Button to run the Query
My Query sentence is:

SELECT tblsch1.datte, tblsch1.room, tblsch1.std_ID
FROM tblsch1
WHERE (((tblsch1.datte) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]) AND ((tblsch1.room)=[Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtroom]))
ORDER BY tblsch1.datte, tblsch1.room;ter code here

For example in Day1 user selects 16/04/2018 and 21/04/2018 in Day2 and enter 6 in Room. Then. when a user clicks Search Button Access displays the query with desired data, otherwise displays "This period has no records".

With same date range user delete 6 and enters  9 and click again button search, then Access displays the query.

With same date range user delete 9 and enters  10 and click again button search, then Access displays the query.

What I am looking for is to allow a user in Room textbox to enter 6 OR 9 OR 10 at a time.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  Your question isn't very clear - can you give specific examples of your data, what you're trying to do, and what it shoudl look like when it's done?  (You want to enter multiple values for "something" and want to query "any" of the values??)  Also, please see "[ask]" and also see how to create a **[mcve]**.  More tips from [so]'s top user, here: [**Writing the perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, your question mentions SQL, SQL, SQL1, and SQL and I see a SQL2 in your code.  Clarity is essential in coding!

Comment: I really appreciated you kindnes reply.I enclose three images as examples. What I am looking for is to type 6 OR 9 OR 10 in room textbox to run the query.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I upload my images or my database file as examples?

Comment: Click the various help links and the (?) icon in the question editor for detailed help with images and formatting.  Stack Overflow does not directly allow sharing of files, primarily because it is unnecessary and not a good practice, especially files with executable code--which includes Access database files.  A good questions has a very specific focus and contains sufficient detail in the question to avoid uploading entire files.  Also, text explanations and properly formatted code are much better than images, so don't include images to avoid describing the problem with words.

Comment: Accepting free-form text criteria with Boolean operators like "6 OR 9 OR 10" would require full parsing of the text followed by proper generation of corresponding SQL... a rather advanced operation.  Access does not handle this kind of input directly.  Perhaps it is possible to build an SQL string in VBA code, but you *at least* risk having improperly formatted SQL criteria, and *at worst* you allow the infamous **SQL injection** security bug.  You will get sharp warnings on SO about inserting user text directly into SQL code, so its best to find another solution.

Comment: If your users know how to use AND and OR, use `BuildCriteria()`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/224961/3820271

Comment: @SebastianSalazar when posting example code or data here, the idea is to post **as little as possible**, narrowing it down to only the problem area.  Please see **[mcve]** for tips about that, as well as the other question-asking-tips I shared above.

Comment: ashleedawg. I will try to be more concise with my problem.

Comment: C Perkins. Is new for me that Access does not accept the inputs I need. I am going to study the link you indicate. I let you know if I am able to adapt the vba code to my search query.

Comment: Actually, it was Andre who gave the link and it looks like exactly what you need.  We are all learning and I did not know about `BuildCriteria()` when I commented.  In the mean time, here is another link to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-buildcriteria-method-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @SebastianSalazar  One last hint... If you place an @ symbol before a username when responding in comments, SO will notify that specific user of your comment. Otherwise they are not notified of the response and may never see it.